# Regex to find string in list in Python 3

Tags: python, regex

How do I get base.php?id=5314 from list?

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.fansubs.ru/search.php'
values = {'Content-Type:' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'query' : 'Boku dake ga Inai Machi' }
d = {}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   the_page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    d[link] = (link.get('href'))
x = (list(d.values()))
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: It is my understanding that he is looking into all `a`s in a page and wants to filter specific `href` values... (stored as list in `x`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the build-in function [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) in combination with a `regex`. Example:

```
import re

# ... your code here ...

x = (list(d.values()))
test = re.compile("base\.php\?id=", re.IGNORECASE)
results = filter(test.search, x)
```

Update based on comment: You can convert the filter results into a list:

```
print(list(results))
```

Example results with the following hard-coded list:

```
x = ["asd/asd/asd.py", "asd/asd/base.php?id=5314",
     "something/else/here/base.php?id=666"]
```

You get:

```
['asd/asd/base.php?id=5314', 'something/else/here/base.php?id=666']
```

This answer is based on [this](http://www.diveintopython.net/functional_programming/filtering_lists.html) page which talks about filtering lists. It has few more implementations to do the same thing, that might suit you better. Hope it helps

Comment: If he is simply looking for an exact match using a regex is an overkill. Just use: `filter(lambda y: 'base.php?id=' in y.lower(), x)`.  Moreover when using regexes to perform exact matches you should use `re.escape` to escape the contents instead of doing it yourself, so `re.compile(re.escape('base.php?id='), re.IGNORECASE)` etc.  this is much more important with user-provided inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a regex directly to `find_all` which will do the filtering for you based on the href with `href=re.compile(...`:

```
import re

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page, 'html.parser')
    d = {link:link["href"] for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(re.escape('base.php?id='))}
```

find_all will only return the a tags that have a href attribute that matches the regex.

which gives you:

```
In [21]:d = {link:link["href"] for link in soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile(re.escape('base.php?id='))}

In [22]: d
Out[22]: {<a href="base.php?id=5314">Boku dake ga Inai Machi <small>(ТВ)</small></a>: 'base.php?id=5314'}
```

Considering you only seem to be looking for one link then it would make more sense just to  use find:

```
In [36]: link = soup.find('a', href=re.compile(re.escape('base.php?id='))

In [37]: link
Out[37]: <a href="base.php?id=5314">Boku dake ga Inai Machi <small>(ТВ)</small></a>

In [38]: link["href"]
Out[38]: 'base.php?id=5314'
```